# Powershell GetEnumerator on HashTable from CSV

Tags: powershell

I would like to understand the best way to only print specific Hashable values coming in from a CSV.

The CSV is formatted like so:

```
Ticket,Last Updated,Priority,Assigned To,Email
2329,1-12-2017,Medium,Assignee1,assignee1@domain.tld
2417,5-23-2016,Low,Assignee1,assignee1@domain.tld
2416,4-20-2017,Medium,Assignee2,assignee2@domain.tld
2463,8-9-2016,Medium,Assignee2,assignee2@domain.tld
2481,3-4-2017,Low,Assignee3,assignee3@domain.tld
2499,2-22-2017,Medium,Assignee4,assignee4@domain.tld
2500,12-20-2016,High,Assignee5,assignee5@domain.tld
2498,11-30-2016,Medium,Assignee5,assignee5@domain.tld
```

In a perfect world the assumption is that I would not know the CSV headers (and thus not the nested hashtable values). I will be looping through to create the hashtable as the code below suggests:

```
$import = Import-Csv -Path .\import.csv|
    Group-Object -Property Email -AsHashTable
foreach ($i in $import.GetEnumerator()){
    $html = $($i.Value) | ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlformat -Body $bodyformat
    $html | Write-Host
}
```

This works fine. The problem is that I would like to exclude the `Email` values from the finished result.

So I figured that, while not ideal, I know what the column headers of this CSV are always going to be, so will this work?:

```
$import = Import-Csv -Path .\import.csv|
    Group-Object -Property Email -AsHashTable
foreach ($i in $import.GetEnumerator()){
    $html = $($i.Value.'Ticket') + $($i.Value.'Last Updated') + $($i.Value.'Priority') + $($i.Value.'Assigned To') 
    $html | Write-Host
}
```

You can see the above code still uses `Group-Object` against the `Email` property but is excluded from the output. However the second I add `| ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlformat -Body $bodyformat` all my data gets turned to numbers representing the character count of the string in the value. Even after reading a lot about the `ConvertTo-Html` issues with string values, being a simpleton in PowerShell, I am still stuck.

In summation:

1. It would be nice to get code that would exclude a Hashtable value (which differs from the current code that is including everything I want)
2. Understand, better, why the first example above can use ``ConvertTo-Html` without issue but the second will not.

Thanks.

**Updated full script:**

*Which currently has an issue described in the comment to Conner below*

```
$htmlformat  = '<title>Stale Tickets</title>'
$htmlformat += '<style type="text/css">'
$htmlformat += "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$htmlformat += "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 7px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$htmlformat += "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 7px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#ffffcc}"
$htmlformat += '</style>'
$bodyformat = '<h3></h3>'
$notice = "<font color='red'><b>This is an automated message.</b></font><br />"

$FromAddress    = "Spiceworks <noreply@domain.tld>"
$ToAddress      = "<My email address for now>"
$Subject        = "You have stale tickets!"
$SMTPserver     = "smtp.whatever.com"

if ((Get-Item "spiceworks_stale_open_ticket_alert.csv").length -gt 0kb)
    {
    $html = Import-Csv -Path .\spiceworks_stale_open_ticket_alert.csv|
    Group-Object -Property Email | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | Select-Object * -Exclude 'Email','Assigned To' | ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlformat -Body $bodyformat
        $html = $html -replace "&lt;","<" -replace "&quot;",'"' -replace "&gt;",">"
        $body = $notice + $html
        Send-MailMessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -subject $Subject -bodyashtml ($body | Out-String) -priority High -smtpServer $SMTPserver        
        }

    }
else {exit;}
```

**Final working iteration for anyone who stumbles across this:**

```
if ((Get-Item "import.csv").length -gt 0kb)
    {
        Import-Csv -Path .\import.csv|
            Group-Object -Property Email|
            ForEach-Object {
                $Html = $_.Group | Select-Object * -Exclude 'Email','Assigned To' | ConvertTo-Html -Head $HtmlFormat -Body $BodyFormat
                $Html = $Html -replace "&lt;","<" -replace "&quot;",'"' -replace "&gt;",">"
                $Body = $notice + $Html + $notice2
                $Subject        = "Inactive Tickets for " + $_.Group[0].'Assigned To'
                $ToAddress = $_.Name
                Send-MailMessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -subject $Subject -BodyAsHtml ($Body | Out-String) -Priority High -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
            }   
    }
else {exit;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if i'm quite understanding what you're trying to do here, if you're looking to Generate a HTML report of Tickets to send, then this should do it (excluding the `Email` part)

```
$HTML = Import-Csv ".\SpiceWorks_Tickets" | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty 'Email' | ConvertTo-Html
```

Using `Select-Object` and the `-ExcludeProperty` param will let you leave out Email completely.

The `ConvertTo-Html` Object takes in a pretty limited set of objects which it knows how to convert, a `PsCustomObject` (which is what `Import-Csv` gives you) will work fine, however a Hashtable will not, so instead of outputting the Inner data, it will give you `System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection` as that's all it knows how to get (I believe it just calls `.ToString()` on it and returns that)

If you'd like to loop through each member of the result of `Group-Object` and turn each Value into its own HTML Table then you can use this:

```
$ImportedCsv | Group-Object -Property Email | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Select-Object * -Exclude 'Email' | ConvertTo-Html
}
```

edit in to send multiple emails:

```
$ImportedCsv | Group-Object -Property Email | ForEach-Object {
    $ToAddress = $_.Name
    $Body = $_.Group | Select-Object * -Exclude 'Email' | ConvertTo-Html -Head $HtmlFormat -Body $BodyFormat
    Send-MailMessage -From $FromAddress -To $ToAddress -Subject $Subject -BodyAsHtml "$Body" -Priority High -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
}
```

Comment: First thanks for your explanations, it is all starting to make sense and I am getting closer because of it. I made an edit to my original post with the latest iteration taking your suggestions. Hopefully it will provide some more scope. Your suggestion to use `Select-Object * -Exclude 'Email'` worked perfect. However instead of the assignee getting a formatted table of only their tickets all assignee's are getting multiple tables of everyone's tickets. Also, eventually, I will need to use `$_.Group.Email` for `$ToAddress` in every loop.

Comment: @NickB I've added in a snippet there that will email each group of results to the `Email` they were grouped by.

Comment: worked perfectly thanks. Added the final script above for posterity - thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove the redundant property from your data:

```
foreach ($key in $import.keys) {
    foreach ($value in $import.$key) {
        $value.PSObject.Properties.Remove("Email")
    }
}
```